# Session.load returns InvocationException when id not in database

Tags: java, hibernate

If I call `Session.load(Class, Serializable)`, e.g. `Session.load(Class<MyClass>, 1L)` where there is no row in the database with id=1, the javassist proxy (?) returned is a `com.sun.jdi.InvocationException`. I'm struggling to understand what's going on here - surely it should simply return `null`?

If I used `LockOptions` in the `session.load(...)` it throws a Hibernate exception saying the row doesn't exist - this makes more sense to me than the former.

This is what I'm struggling to code:

```
public MyClass ensureEntity(Long id) {
    MyClass entity = (MyClass)Session.load(Class<MyClass>, 1L);
    if(entity == null) {
        entity = new MyClass(id);
        getSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
    }
    return entity;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `get()`. It is expected for `load()` to throw an exception. From [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#load%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29) of `load()`:

> You should not use this method to determine if an instance exists (use get()  instead). Use this only to retrieve an instance that you assume exists, where non-existence would be an actual error.